# Position a div box absolute under another absolute positioned div box without knowing it's height

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I made a website where I placed several pictures in div boxes and placed them absolute in a position I want them to be.

`.char1 - .char5` already have the right position. Now i want `.char6 - .char10` to align directly under `.char1 - .char5`. What would be a clever way to accomplish this? In my code it only works as long as I don't change the screen size.

Also all my `.char` divs nearly have the same values, besides the the "left" and "top" positions. Is there a way to shorten this?

Thank you very much.

```css
* {
    background-color: #151515;
}

.h {
    align-self: center;
    width: 96%;
    height 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-color: 817B6F;

}
.chars {
    display: flex;
    width: 10%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: 817B6F;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 25%;
}


    .char1 {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    background-color: 817B6F;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    top: 10%;
    height: auto;
    left: 21.5%;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0.7%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
}
.char2 {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    background-color: 817B6F;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    top: 10%;
    height: auto;
    left: 32.9%;
    padding:0.7%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;

}

.char3 {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    background-color: 817B6F;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    top: 10%;
    height: auto;
    left: 44.3%;
    padding:0.7%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;

}

.char4 {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    background-color: 817B6F;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    top: 10%;
    height: auto;
    left: 55.7%;
    padding:0.7%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
}

.char5 {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    background-color: 817B6F;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    top: 10%;
    height: auto;
    left: 67.1%;
    padding:0.7%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.char6 {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    background-color: 817B6F;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    top: 33%;
    height: auto;
    left: 21.5%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0.7%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
}

.char7 {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    background-color: 817B6F;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    top: 33%;
    height: auto;
    left: 32.9%;
    padding:0.7%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;

}

.char8 {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    background-color: 817B6F;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    top: 33%;
    height: auto;
    left: 44.3%;
    padding:0.7%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;

}

.char9 {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    background-color: 817B6F;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    top: 33%;
    height: auto;
    left: 55.7%;
    padding:0.7%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
}

.char10 {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    background-color: 817B6F;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    top: 33%;
    height: auto;
    left: 67.1%;
    padding:0.7%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="char1">

<img class= "h" name= Warrior src="http://placehold.it/256" />
</div>

<div class="char2">

<img class= "h" name= Warrior src="http://placehold.it/256" />
</div>

<div class="char3">

<img class= "h" name= Warrior src="http://placehold.it/256" />
</div>

<div class="char4">

<img class= "h" name= Warrior src="http://placehold.it/256" />
</div>

<div class="char5">

<img class= "h" name= Warrior src="http://placehold.it/256" />
</div>

<div class="char6">

<img class= "h" name= Warrior src="http://placehold.it/256" />
</div>

<div class="char7">

<img class= "h" name= Warrior src="http://placehold.it/256" />
</div>

<div class="char8">

<img class= "h" name= Warrior src="http://placehold.it/256" />
</div>

<div class="char9">

<img class= "h" name= Warrior src="http://placehold.it/256" />
</div>

<div class="char10">

<img class= "h" name= Warrior src="http://placehold.it/256" />
</div>
```

Comment: Add html code also for better understanding

Comment: All programming is a bunch of `1`s and `0`s we, humans, use as a convention in order to communicate and achieve certain goals. The requirement should be to display images in a certain manner on certain (or all) devices/browsers. If it is ***to display the images using `position:absolute`***, you are **Doing it wrong™**. Remove `position:absolute` from an element and it will start taking up space in the flow of the document and behave exactly like you are asking. Now, what is your ***real*** requirement?

Comment: My plan is, to have these elements align with a margin of 10% to the top and 25% to the left and right and ca. 50% margin to the bottom. It is div boxes, containing picutes I want to be aligned in two rows. When you click one of these elements, a box in the bottom of the screen will pop up, containing a confimation button. If you press the confirmation button, the div with the picture should be moved to the left of the screen, using css animations.

Comment: I added a `general principle` solution, using flexbox. You can play with it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/xfaog5uf/) and modify margins, positioning, etc... Cheers.

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Using absolute positioning for placement is usually a bad idea, especially in responsive design. You're better off using relative or static (default) positioning and using margins to achieve your desired result, as your boxes then will flow naturally as they appear in the DOM.

Also you should look into the DRY principle, as in Don't Repeat Yourself. In your case, you could just use the same class for all your boxes and style accordingly.

Comment: **This is really a comment, not an answer.**